# Joptionpane Message dialog in catch block

Tags: java

I am copying directories and files from one windows server to another windows server using Swing and that works fine. I want to have a Joption Messagedialog pop up when the windows server goes down unexpectedly while copying so gave it in the catch block but it never dispays the pop up when the server goes down(I restart the windows server manually while copying but cannot see the pop up). Can someone help and here is the code

```
try {
    textarea.append("Copying " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()
        + "   to " + targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
    is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));

    long fileBytes = sourceFile.length();
    long soFar = 0;

    int theByte;

    while ((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) {
        bos.write(theByte);

        setProgress((int) (copiedBytes++ * 100 / totalBytes));
        publish((int) (soFar++ * 100 / fileBytes));
    }

    bis.close();
    bos.close();
    publish(100);
    textarea.append(" Done!\n");
} catch (Exception excep) {
    task.cancel(true);
    bos.flush();
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
    jf2 = new JFrame();
    jf2.setSize(401, 401);
    jf2.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf2.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf2,
        "The Server is not accessible or it may be down because of Network Issue",
        "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} finally {
    if (bis != null) {
        bis.close();
    }
    if (bos != null) {
        bos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that one or more of the close statements is either hanging or raising a new exception (possibly also coming from the task.cancel). Try moving the JOptionPane above these statements. If that works, isolate each close statement within there own try-catch

Comment: Consider using better code indentation and wrapping when posting code on this site. If we can read your code easily, we can understand it more easily and be better able to help you.

Comment: Your code snippet suggests that you may be running afoul of Swing's threading rules. It's hard to know though based on this snippet. Also what is the purpose of creating a ghost JFrame for the JOptionPane?

Comment: MadProgrammer, Thanks for your help. Moving the JOptionPane above worked

Comment: -1 for making trashgod do your grunt-work code formatting for you.

Comment: @user1815823 I've provide a basic example, but is still violating Swing's Thread Rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your try-catch is a little akward.

You try and close the streams on the event of an exception AND within the `finally` block.

Finally is guaranteed to be called regardless, so you can save yourself some code by using it to close of the steams..

```
try {
    textarea.append("Copying " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "   to " + targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
    is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));

    long fileBytes = sourceFile.length();
    long soFar = 0;

    int theByte;

    while ((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) {
        bos.write(theByte);

        setProgress((int) (copiedBytes++ * 100 / totalBytes));
        publish((int) (soFar++ * 100 / fileBytes));
    }

    // Not required, finally will take care of it...
    //bis.close();
    //bos.close();
    publish(100);
    // !! THIS IS VERY, VERY NAUGHTY !!
    textarea.append(" Done!\n");
} catch (Exception excep) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Server is not accessible or it may be down because of Network Issue", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    task.cancel(true);

} finally {

    try {
        // techniqually, this gets taken care of when you close the stream,
        // but I tend not to trust it either...
        bos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

It appears that your code is using a `SwingWorker`, but you call `textarea.append(" Done!\n")` within it.  This is VERY, VERY bad.

Your `process` method needs to be capable of doing this...Basically when you `process` receives `100`, it should be capable of updating the text area.

You could also allow the exception to handled else where, allowing the `doInBackground` method to throw the exception.  This would allow you to use the `done` method and the `get` method to determine if an exception has occurred, the added benefit of which is `done` is called within the EDT

Answer (score 1):

For a start, I don't like all the manual resource management, so I'd change that to use Java 7's [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to do it for you, which allows the removal of the finally block and all instances of `close()` and `flush()` (by the way, close calls flush so you didn't need both anyway.

Secondly, I don't know if that message box declaration is valid, the Javadoc for `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` says the first parameter should be `Component parentComponent`, but you're declaring a new invisible JFrame as that instead, so if this code you posted is inside a JFrame class, pass in `this` instead. In full, I'd give this a go:

```
try(BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile)))
{
    textarea.append("Copying " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() +
                    " to " + targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
    long fileBytes = sourceFile.length();
    long soFar = 0;
    int theByte;
    while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1)
    {
        bos.write(theByte);
        setProgress((int) (copiedBytes++ * 100 / totalBytes));
        publish((int) (soFar++ * 100 / fileBytes));
    }
    publish(100);
    textarea.append(" Done!\n");
}
catch(Exception excep)
{
    task.cancel(true);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The Server is not accessible or it may be down because of Network Issue", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```